# AngularJS $http request OPTIONS and POST

Tags: angularjs, javascript-framework

I'm trying to get the POST error response in $http AngularJS, but when I watch the response variable in catch, I get the preflight OPTION response. How can I get the POST response, instead of OPTION?

My OPTION returns 200 OK and my POST returns 402.
But my reason.data is null

Thanks in advance

```
$http.post(url, data, {headers:{}})
.then( function ( response ) {})
.catch( function ( reason ) {
    console.log(reason);
});
```

---EDIT---

Actually the POST response seems OK, but my reason returns status: -1 and data: null

Comment: If the `OPTIONS` request is failing and hitting the `catch` block then the `POST` will not be performed.

Comment: With pre-flight OPTION requests,  the browser never passes the OPTION response to JavaScript. If the OPTION request fails, the browser will block the POST request. The AngularJS $http service returns a status of `-1`. All responses are blocked from JavaScript.